# How to exclude records by category

Tags: mysql

I have statement:

```
$statement_q = "
SELECT img 
     , title
     , time
     , videos.id 
     , date 
  FROM videos 
  JOIN videocategories 
    ON videos.id = videocategories.video_id 
  JOIN categories 
    ON categories.id = videocategories.category_id 
 WHERE categories.name != 'Western'
 GROUP 
    BY videos.id 
 ORDER 
    BY videos.id 
 LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page}";
```

Hierarchy:

[image]

If movie have more than one category it will show it!

Movie 1 : Werstern, Adventure (it will show it)

Movie 2 : Western (one category so it not will show it)

How to exclude western movies?

Comment: I think we need more information on your table metadata

Comment: But everything is here. I just do not know how to change it...

Comment: NO, we can guess.  Is the user entering two keywords ?  And whats the difference between video categories and categories ?

Comment: Does `categories` table contain multiple `category.name` for one `video.id`?

Comment: @Phillip, wouldn't say so, videocategories should handle multiple genres, if i am right?

Comment: movies usually have several categories so if i add inner join i have as many movies as there are categories! And when i want exlude category I excude record with that category, not a movie.. and thats is the problem.

Comment: A GROUP BY clause with no aggregating functions is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.  I can't create the tables right now to verify it.

```
$statement_q = "SELECT img,title,time,videos.id as id,date FROM videos 
INNER JOIN videocategories ON videos.id = videocategories.video_id 
INNER JOIN categories on categories.id = videocategories.category_id 
WHERE categories.name != 'Western'
AND not exists (select v.id from videocategories v where v.video_id = videos.id
                and v.category_id <> videocategories.category_id)
GROUP by videos.id 
ORDER BY videos.id 
LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page}";
```

Comment: i get error :  Unknown column 'v.id' in 'field list'

Comment: You shouldn't, did you put the v in after videocategories ?  That aliases this instance of the table so that the engine can distinguish between the two.  If you did and it still fails, I will rewrite the whole thing and alias the first one properly, shortly.

Comment: Yes i did. "select v.id from videocategories"   videocategories dont have field id , its only ( video_id , category_id) hierarchy is higher

Comment: I am still not assured that you have.  I mean this one  "videocategories v where", sandwiched between the two words.  It aliases the table to distinguish it from the first use.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS video_category;

CREATE TABLE video_category
(video_id INT NOT NULL
,category_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(video_id,category_id)
);

INSERT INTO video_category VALUES
(101,1),(101,2),(102,1),(102,3);

SELECT * FROM video_category;
+----------+-------------+
| video_id | category_id |
+----------+-------------+
|      101 |           1 |
|      101 |           2 |
|      102 |           1 |
|      102 |           3 |
+----------+-------------+

SELECT * 
  FROM video_category x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN video_category y 
    ON y.video_id = x.video_id 
   AND y.category_id = 2;
+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+
| video_id | category_id | video_id | category_id |
+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+
|      101 |           1 |      101 |           2 |
|      101 |           2 |      101 |           2 |
|      102 |           1 |     NULL |        NULL |
|      102 |           3 |     NULL |        NULL |
+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+

SELECT DISTINCT x.video_id 
           FROM video_category x 
           LEFT 
           JOIN video_category y 
             ON y.video_id = x.video_id 
            AND y.category_id = 2 
          WHERE y.category_id IS NULL;
+----------+
| video_id |
+----------+
|      102 |
+----------+
```